# how to convert multiple date formats in one format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe with date column as `object`

```
   ID      Date                  Volume
   0       13-02-2018 00:06       85
   1       13-02-2018 00:10       70
   2       13-02-2018 00:11       100
   3       2018-02-13 06:30       123
   4       02-13-2018 07:56       100
```

I want to convert it to following one format

```
   ID      Date                  Volume
   0       2018-02-13 00:06       85
   1       2018-02-13 00:10       70
   2       2018-02-13 00:11       100
   3       2018-02-13 06:30       123
   4       2018-02-13 07:56       100
```

I am trying to achieve this by following command

```
df['Date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')[0])
```

But it throws an error. How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: Do you want the final column to be in datetime format, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes final column in datetime format

Comment: Also, without the hour format I assume

Comment: Yes. Hour format does not matter

Comment: But is it a problem if you have the hour format too? If yes, then it's easy. Else, I have been struggling to get a solution too. :D

Comment: Its ok if I have hour format as well.

Comment: Posted the answer, please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

link:  [Series.dt.strftime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Answer (score -2):

**Import time**

```
Localtime= time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
Print(localtime)
```

Check if this we work