# Transform date format on DataFrame when same column has different formats

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in pandas python, and i am loading a file and saving it in a DataFrame that looks like this.

`27      9-7-2019      30.029     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          30029

28      9-7-2019      40.575     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          40575

29      9-7-2019      31.929     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          31929

30      9-7-2019      133.53     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO         133530

31      9-7-2019      62.426     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          62426

..           ...         ...        ...    ...         ...            ...

476     9/7/2019      34.397     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          34397

477     9/7/2019      89.827     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          89827

478     9/7/2019      37.973     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          37973

479     9/7/2019       29.98     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          29980

480     9/7/2019      25.992     MOROSO  MOVIL          NO          25992`

The problem is in the second column where the dates comes in different formats, `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy`, and i need it to transform it to datetime.

i have tried doing the transformation, but this transform to NaT the dates with format `dd/mm/yyyy`

[image]

how can i solve this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781019/how-to-convert-multiple-date-formats-in-one-format-in-pandas) answer.

Comment: Just let pandas handle it for you. `pd.to_datetime(df['FEC_VENCIMIE'])` or another option is to replace the "/" with   `pd.to_datetime(df['FEC_VENCIMIE'].str.replace('/', '-'))` but you should have to.

Answer (score 1):

Just let pandas guess:

```
df['due-date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['due-date'])
```

Output:

```
0   2019-09-07
1   2019-09-07
2   2019-09-07
3   2019-09-07
4   2019-09-07
5   2019-09-07
6   2019-09-07
7   2019-09-07
8   2019-09-07
9   2019-09-07
Name: due-date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: There's a striking error in that you're representing `9/7/2019` as `2019-09-07` whereas it should be `2019-07-09`. You likely want `dayfirst=True`

Comment: That much depends on where you lives. 9/11/2001 means Sep 11, 2011.

Comment: Yep, that's obvious, but OP explicitly stated the formats in the question hahaha ;}

Comment: haha, totally overlooked that part. You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('/', '-')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Output:

```
0   27  2019-09-07  30.029  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  30029
1   28  2019-09-07  40.575  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  40575
2   29  2019-09-07  31.929  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  31929
3   30  2019-09-07  133.530 MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  133530
4   31  2019-09-07  62.426  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  62426
5   476 2019-09-07  34.397  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  34397
6   477 2019-09-07  89.827  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  89827
7   478 2019-09-07  37.973  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  37973
8   479 2019-09-07  29.980  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  29980
9   480 2019-09-07  25.992  MOROSO  MOVIL   NO  25992
```